# Check if next element is selectable in jQuery and if so, select it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a easy and simple web design app (mainly for touch devices) that even my nephew can use. However I came across an annoying problem today. After hours of trial and error I'm now asking for help :(.

My problem is the next and forward arrow buttons (**not** the squared ones).

What I'm doing is when I click say the next button (`#movenext`) I'm first looking to see if there's a next element/tag and if there is I then am selecting that element with a class called `.selected`. If I've selected the last element I want to be alerted that that's the last child of the parent I've selected.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.

[image]

```
// Make Next Selected 
$("#movenext").click(function() {
  if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
    // Detect If New Selection Has Tag
    if ( $(".selected").next().prop("tagName") === [undefined, false] ) {
      // No Selection
      alert("last child selected");
      $("#deselectelement").trigger("click");
    } else {
      $(".selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
      $("#selected-tag").val( $(".selected").prop("tagName").toLowerCase() );
      $("#selected-element").val( $(".selected").attr("class").replace(/ /g," ") );
    }
  } else {
    // No element selected
    $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild, #editelement, #deselectelement, #delelement, #editTagAttributes").addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Draggable FunctionBar
  $(".functionbar").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".handlesbar"
  });

  // Select Elements
  var SelectElements = function() {
    $("#dynamic-storage").children().on("mouseup touchend", function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      }

      $(this).addClass("selected");

      // Check if first & last child is selected
      if ( $(this).is(":first-child") && $(this).is(":last-child") ) {
        if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
          $("#tochild").removeClass("hide");
          return false;
        }
        // Check if first child is selected
      } else if ( $(this).is(":first-child") ) {
        if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
          $("#movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
          return false;
        }
        // Check if last child is selected
      } else if ( $(this).is(":last-child") ) {
        if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
        }
        $("#moveprev, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
      } else {
        // Check if in middle
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
      }
    });
  };
  // Call Selection
  var CallSelection = function() {
    // Check if first & last child is selected
    if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
        $("#tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if first child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
        $("#movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if last child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
      }
      $("#moveprev, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      // Check if in middle
      $("#moveprev, #movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    }
  };
  // Clear Selection
  var ClearSelection = function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
  };
  SelectElements();
});
```

```css
/* Body */
#dynamic-storage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* FunctionBar */
.functionbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 998;
}

.functionbar .handlesbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  font: 24px arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(180, 0%, 0%, .75);
  word-spacing: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.functionbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(180, 0%, 90%);
}

.functionbar .active {
  color: #9cf;
}

.functionbar .hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Dialog Sec */
.functionbar .reveal {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.functionbar .reveal, .functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  font-family: arial;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea, #change-selected-tag, #confirm-style {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}

#dynamic-storage .selected {
  outline: 2px dotted #69f;
}

/* Addable Elements */
.functionbar .addcontent {
  text-align: center;
}

.functionbar .addcontent .element, .functionbar .editcontent .element {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.67);
  color: #262B2F;
}
.functionbar .element:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.functionbar .element .fa {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.functionbar .element h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- FunctionBar -->
    <div class="functionbar">
      
      <div class="handlesbar">
        <div class="handlesbar-page1">
          <a id="moveprev" title="Select Previous Element" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="movenext" title="Select Next Element" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="toparent" class="hide" title="Select Parent" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="tochild" title="Select First Index" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></span>
          </a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="dynamic-storage">
      <div class="header" align="center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
        <span>Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div class="header selected" align="left">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="header" align="right">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through. If you want to know if a selector matches anything, use `if ($("selector").length > 1)`.

Comment: What do you think `if ( $(".selected").next().prop("tagName") === [undefined, false] )` and the other, similar if tests are doing? (Hint: those condition are *never* going to be true. `if ( $(".selected").parent() === true )` will never be true either.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Instead of giving us a code dump of your project, please _simplify_ the problem to an example that includes just what you are asking about, and we can show you how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem for next, previous & child selections.

What I did was I checked to see if the `.selected` class is the `:first-child` or `:last-child` and if it's the first child to hide previous and if it's the last child to hide next. This way will prevent any errors from occurring using the next and previous buttons.

Here's the bit of code I used.

```
// If prev element accessable make it selectable
var movePrev = function() {
  // Detect If New Selection Has Tag
  if ( $(".selected").prev().is(":visible") ) {
    // Show/Add Tag & Class
    $("#selected-tag").val( $(".selected").prev().prop("tagName").toLowerCase() );
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected").prev().addClass("selected");
    $("#selected-element").val( $(".selected").attr("class").replace(/ /g," ") );
    $(".code").val( $(".selected").html() );
    checkParent();
  }

  // Check if first & last child is selected
  if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
    if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
      // Do nothing
    } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
      $("#toparent, #tochild, #editelement, #deselectelement, #delelement, #editTagAttributes").removeClass("hide");
      return false;
    }
  // Check if first child is selected
  } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
    if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
      $("#movenext, #toparent, #tochild, #editelement, #deselectelement, #delelement, #editTagAttributes").removeClass("hide");
      return false;
    }
    // Check if last child is selected
  } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
    if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
    }
    $("#moveprev, #toparent, #tochild, #editelement, #deselectelement, #delelement, #editTagAttributes").removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    // Check if in middle
    $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild, #editelement, #deselectelement, #delelement, #editTagAttributes").removeClass("hide");
  }
};
```

Child button solution..

```
// If child is accessable make it selectable
var check4Child = function() {
  // Check if it has child if not hide button
  if ( $(".selected").children().length <= 0 ) {
    $("#tochild").addClass("hide");
    return false;
  }
  if ( $(".selected").children().is(":hidden") ) {
    $("#tochild").addClass("hide");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Parent button solution...

```
// #dynamic-storage & .functionbar must not be selectable
var checkParent = function() {
 if ( $(".selected").parent().is("#dynamic-storage") ) {
    $("#toparent").addClass("hide");
  }
};
```

Now for the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Draggable FunctionBar
  $(".functionbar").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".handlesbar"
  });

  // Select Elements
  var SelectElements = function() {
    $("#dynamic-storage").children().on("mouseup touchend", function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      }

      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $("#selected-element").val( $(this).attr("class").replace(/ /g," "));
      $("#selected-tag").val( $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() );
      $(".code").val( $(".selected").html() );

      checkParent();

      // Check if first & last child is selected
      if ( $(this).is(":first-child") && $(this).is(":last-child") ) {
        if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
          $("#tochild").removeClass("hide");
          return false;
        }
        // Check if first child is selected
      } else if ( $(this).is(":first-child") ) {
        if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
          $("#movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
          return false;
        }
        // Check if last child is selected
      } else if ( $(this).is(":last-child") ) {
        if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
        }
        $("#moveprev, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
      } else {
        // Check if in middle
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
      }

      check4Child();
    });
  };
  // Call Selection
  var CallSelection = function() {
    checkParent();

    // Check if first & last child is selected
    if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
        $("#tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if first child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
        $("#movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if last child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
      }
      $("#moveprev, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      // Check if in middle
      $("#moveprev, #movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    }

    check4Child();
  };
  // Clear Selection
  var ClearSelection = function() {
    $("#selected-tag, #selected-element, .code").val("");
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
  };
  // If prev element accessable make it selectable
  var movePrev = function() {
    // Detect If New Selection Has Tag
    if ( $(".selected").prev().is(":visible") ) {
      // Show/Add Tag & Class
      $(".selected").removeClass("selected").prev().addClass("selected");
      checkParent();
    }

    // Check if first & last child is selected
    if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
        $("#toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if first child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
        $("#movenext, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if last child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
      }
      $("#moveprev, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      // Check if in middle
      $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    }
  };
  // If next element accessable make it selectable
  var moveNext = function() {
    // Detect If New Selection Has Tag
    if ( $(".selected").next().is(":visible") ) {
      // Show/Add Tag & Class
      $(".selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
      checkParent();
    }

    // Check if first & last child is selected
    if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
        $("#toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if first child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
      if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
        $("#movenext, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }
      // Check if last child is selected
    } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
      if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
        // Do nothing
      } else {
        $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
      }
      $("#moveprev, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      // Check if in middle
      $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
    }
    check4Child();
  };
  // If child is accessable make it selectable
  var check4Child = function() {
    // Check if it has child if not hide button
    if ( $(".selected").children().length <= 0 ) {
      $("#tochild").addClass("hide");
      return false;
    }
    if ( $(".selected").children().is(":hidden") ) {
      $("#tochild").addClass("hide");
      return false;
    }
  };
  // #dynamic-storage & .functionbar must not be selectable
  var checkParent = function() {
    if ( $(".selected").parent().is("#dynamic-storage") ) {
      $("#toparent").addClass("hide");
    }
  };
  SelectElements();

  // Handles Next/Prev/Parent/Children Selections
  $(function() {
    // Make Parent Selected 
    $("#toparent").click(function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        if ( $(".selected").parent().is("#dynamic-storage") ) {
          $("#toparent").addClass("hide");
        } else {
          $(".selected").parent().addClass("selected").children().removeClass("selected");
          movePrev();
          CallSelection();
        }

        // Check if first & last child is selected
        if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") && $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
          if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
            // Do nothing
          } else if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            $("#moveprev, #movenext").addClass("hide");
            $("#tochild").removeClass("hide");
            return false;
          }
          // Check if first child is selected
        } else if ( $(".selected").is(":first-child") ) {
          if ( $("#moveprev").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            $("#moveprev").addClass("hide");
            $("#movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
            return false;
          }
          // Check if last child is selected
        } else if ( $(".selected").is(":last-child") ) {
          if ( $("#movenext").hasClass() === "hide" ) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            $("#movenext").addClass("hide");
          }
          $("#moveprev, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        } else {
          // Check if in middle
          $("#moveprev, #movenext, #tochild").removeClass("hide");
        }
      } else {
        // No element selected
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
      }
    });

    // Make Child Selected 
    $("#tochild").click(function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        // Detect First Tag
        if ( $(".selected").children().first().length > 0 ) {
          $(".selected").removeClass("selected").children().first().addClass("selected");
          movePrev();
          CallSelection();
          check4Child();
        } else {
          ClearSelection();
        }
      } else {
        // No element selected
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
      }
    });

    // Make Previous Selected 
    $("#moveprev").click(function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        movePrev();
        CallSelection();
        check4Child();
      } else {
        // No element selected
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
      }
    });

    // Make Next Selected 
    $("#movenext").click(function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        moveNext();
        CallSelection();
      } else {
        // No element selected
        $("#moveprev, #movenext, #toparent, #tochild").addClass("hide");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* Body */
#dynamic-storage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* FunctionBar */
.functionbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 998;
}

.functionbar .handlesbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  font: 24px arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(180, 0%, 0%, .75);
  word-spacing: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.functionbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(180, 0%, 90%);
}

.functionbar .active {
  color: #9cf;
}

.functionbar .hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Dialog Sec */
.functionbar .reveal {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.functionbar .reveal, .functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  font-family: arial;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea, #change-selected-tag, #confirm-style {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}

#dynamic-storage .selected {
  outline: 2px dotted #69f;
}

/* Addable Elements */
.functionbar .addcontent {
  text-align: center;
}

.functionbar .addcontent .element, .functionbar .editcontent .element {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.67);
  color: #262B2F;
}
.functionbar .element:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.functionbar .element .fa {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.functionbar .element h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- FunctionBar -->
    <div class="functionbar">
      
      <div class="handlesbar">
        <div class="handlesbar-page1">
          <a id="moveprev" title="Select Previous Element" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="movenext" title="Select Next Element" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="toparent" class="hide" title="Select Parent" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up"></span>
          </a> 
          <a id="tochild" title="Select First Index" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></span>
          </a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="dynamic-storage">
      <div class="header" align="center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
        <span>Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div class="header selected" align="left">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="header" align="right">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```